# Saxon: access to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to obtain a data from SQL Server from XSL template with using of Saxon SQL Extension. But I get an error:

> Error in xsl:copy-of/@select on line 36 column 60 of sqlserver_books.xsl:
>   XTDE1450: Unknown extension instruction
>   Unknown extension instruction

- Saxon version: SaxonPE 9-7-0-11
- Java version: 1.8.0_60

Command:

```
SET CLASSPATH=SaxonPE9-7-0-11J/saxon9pe.jar;SaxonPE9-7-0-11J/saxon9-sql.jar;sqljdbc4.jar
java -cp %CLASSPATH% net.sf.saxon.Transform -config:config.xml -it:main -xsl:sqlserver_books.xsl -o:out.xml
```

**sqlserver_books.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
    xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"    
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon sql">

    <xsl:param name="jdbc.driver" as="xsd:string" select="string('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')" />
    <xsl:param name="jdbc.database" as="xsd:string" select="string('jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test')" />
    <xsl:param name="jdbc.user" as="xsd:string" select="string('testuser')" />
    <xsl:param name="jdbc.pass" as="xsd:string" select="string('pass')" />

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="element-available('sql:connect')">
                <xsl:variable name="sql.conn" as="java:java.sql.Connection">
                    <sql:connect driver="{$jdbc.driver}" database="{$jdbc.database}" user="{$jdbc.user}" password="{$jdbc.pass}">
                        <xsl:fallback>
                            <xsl:message terminate="yes">SQL extensions are not installed</xsl:message>
                        </xsl:fallback>
                    </sql:connect>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="sql.books" as="element()*">
                    <sql:query connection="$sql.conn" table="dbo.Books" column="*" />
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:copy-of select="$sql.books" />
                <sql:close connection="$sql.conn" />
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:message terminate="yes">sql:connect element is not available</xsl:message>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration" edition="PE">    
  <global allowExternalFunctions="true" versionOfXml="1.0"/>
    <xslt>
        <extensionElement namespace="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
            factory="net.sf.saxon.option.sql.SQLElementFactory"/>
    </xslt>
  </configuration>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried the old version **saxonb9-1-0-8j** with the commands:

```
SET CLASSPATH=saxonb9-1-0-8j/saxon9.jar;saxonb9-1-0-8j/saxon9-sql.jar;sqljdbc4.jar
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:main -xsl:sqlserver_books.xsl  -o:out.xml
```

and after changing '*xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"*' to '*xmlns:sql="java://net.sf.saxon.sql.SQLElementFactory"*'
everything is working. But why the latest version isn't working?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the `-t` option in `java -cp %CLASSPATH% net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -config:config.xml -it:main -xsl:sqlserver_books.xsl -o:out.xml` and check the output whether it is really PE with a license running when you get the error?

Comment: I get "No license file found - running with licensable features disabled". It means that 'SQL Extension' doesn't work without license?

Comment: Saxon PE and EE are commercial products you can only run with a license, you need at least a trial license to test and use any features like extensions that are not supported in the open source HE edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Martin Honnen has given you the answer: you are running without a license file.